# Node.JS: fs.readFile not working on Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, readfile, fs

I'm trying to read some xml files, and when I test the code in my computer (OS X) it's working really good, without problems, but when I test the code in a Ubuntu 16 Server in DigitalOcean, I get nothing...
I'm using `fs.watch()` and yes, it has nothing to be with the route because the program knows theres a new file in the directory but when I try to read the console.log prints nothing. I've already tried with `readFile()` and `readFileSync()`...
I'm sending the files to the directory using `scp`

I'm getting the `eventType` logs when I catch a file into the directory and the `console.log("filename: ",filename)` is giving me the name of the file, so, that's why I suggest the `fs.readFileSync()` is the problem

Any suggestion?

```
    let dir = __dirname + '/../files/'
    fs.watch(dir, 'utf8',(eventType, filename) => {
      console.log("eventType: ", eventType)
      if(eventType === 'rename' && filename) {
        console.log("filename: ",filename)
        fs.readFile(`${dir}${filename}`, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
          if(err) console.log("error: ", err)
          console.log(data)
        }) 
   //  let data = fs.readFileSync(`${dir}${filename}`, 'utf8')
   //  console.log("DATA: ", data)<-- as I said, I've already tried with both, readFile() and readFileSync()
      }
    });
```

Comment: Does fs.watch trigger at all?  You get some "eventType" logs or no?

Comment: Yeah, ```fs.watch()``` is working and logs when I send a new file to the directory. and the ```console.log("filename: ", filename)``` is sending me the name of the file without problem. @James

Comment: Maybe post what you do see in your logs, because in your question you said you get nothing.

Comment: I just updated the post with that, @James

Comment: have you tried `fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, filename), 'UTF-8', callback);` ? I could be mistaken, but I thought path.resolve was the correct way to get the file path.

Comment: Just a guess, but what usually bites me when moving to linux from macOS is case-sensitive file names.

Comment: I just changed the code with ```fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(dir,filename), 'utf8')```  and also tried ```fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname,`../files/${filename}`), 'utf8')``` and still the same, I get the read file in my computer but in the Ubuntu not. @CharlieWeems

Comment: all the filenames are in caps, but I just tried to log the path```console.log("path name: ",path.resolve(__dirname,`../files/${filename}`))```  and everything it's ok. @JimBaldwin

Comment: What operation are you testing this with?  Uploading a new file to that directory via SCP?  The underlying process that handles file system events for fs.watch varies by OS, so inotify (Linux) is probably behaving differently than kqueue (macOS).  I wonder if you are now getting an event when the SCP transfer first starts which returns an empty file.

Comment: Well, the app should read an upload xml file where I should read the data from a user like email, name etc... I'm using SCP because I have not developed yet the upload files module but when I send the file by SCP I'm catching the event and the filename (those I get in the console.logs with evenType and filename) but not the content... @James

Comment: Ok, I just wrote another script where I just read a file that is already in a directory and it's reading the file without problem... so the problem is when I'm sending with ```scp``` @James

Comment: Rather than logging the file's contents is there a way you can log its size?  If you get zeros (or indeed anything other than the correct size) you know something weird is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `path.resolve()` and `readFile()` methods. To fix this issue, I used [resolve-path](https://github.com/pillarjs/resolve-path) and [parseurl](https://github.com/pillarjs/parseurl) libraries.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.